A childrens/young adult book about a boy in a secret organization
Looking for a book I read long ago, so my memory is very blurred, some details are likely not accurate. All I can recall is a boy that is taken to an organization of a bunch of kids in similar age, and the boy is initially doubtful and stubborn about joining. He is given a nutrient bar that apparently to him tastes like a Snickers? or a candy bar. This next detail I am unsure if it happens as a result of the bar or another cause, but he becomes almost hypnotized and susceptible to whatever the authoritative figure is (that he is being stubborn towards) and starts acting like a dog (barking?). I believe the book utilizes the word canine/"K-9". He then snaps back to reality where his peers are laughing at him.
